# Navbar settings

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-layout

Possible to have the Navbar in a fixed position as in https://stackoverflow.com/ ?

I believe it is useful to have it in the view when scrolling down long posts, anyone else have an opinion on this?

[image]

Comment: The new nav bar is part  of a overhaul to the site in general, along with the new tabs. It'll make its way to the community sites once they finalize the design (Which may take a while, consider how hard myself and others are willing to fight for a black nav bar over a white nav bar, and other bikeshed issues). In the meantime, you'll just have to get used to the home key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really like the Stack Overflow floating nav bar, as it does save me from pressing Home or scrolling up all the time; if I were a power user there, I might even get a chance to use it.

However... if we're going to talk about navigation, the floating bar would be a step in the right direction, but I'd rather have list navigation buttons, very poorly prototyped below:

[image: Navigation Buttons]

This is similar to how you can browse CraigsList by performing a search, and you're then given an option to go left (towards top of list), up to list, and right (towards bottom of list).

Having a floating nav bar is really "cool," but having features that let power users navigate their preferred domain would be even cooler. For example, we click on a tag, get a list of all those questions, then we can just navigate through them without keeping a separate tab open.

It's not unusual for me to have five or more SFSE tabs open in my browser simply because navigation isn't that great, and I'm sure that our regulars would probably like more power.

Alternatively, if we could see a feed of new questions (like we do comments and rep changes), preferably in the aforementioned floating nav bar, I'd be even happier. I could keep one tab open and see new questions are available. This already happens on the home page, so I know the API is already there, we just need the system to feed us questions.

Or, I need to find a Stackaholics Anonymous club. Either way, this site still has one of the better navigation systems around, but I think it'd be awesome to have a few extra features.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion if we have option to navigate to next or Previous Question quickly that would be great.We can have Previous and Next Option in Top of the page and end of the Page would be easy to slide over different Questions instead of scrolling up and Navigating.

**In Top Of Page:**
[image]

**In Bottom of page:**
[image]